# How to find a sum of the series? $ S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\sin nx}{n}+\frac{\cos nx}{n^2}\right) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

> How to find a sum of the series?
>   $$
> S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\sin nx}{n}+\frac{\cos nx}{n^2}\right)
> $$

I tried to do something like that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&z=\cos x+i\sin x\\
&S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{Im}\left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{Re}\left(\frac{z^n}{n^2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
However, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^2}=\text{Li}_2(z)$, and I have no idea what $\text{Re}(\text{Li}_2(z))$ is here.

So, I'd be very grateful if someone pointed out the right way of solving this problem.

Comment: Fourier series?

Comment: You should read something about Bernoulli polynomials (for instance wiki). The first term is $-B_1({x\over 2\pi})$, the second $B_2({x\over 2\pi})$. So that your result is (on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ a polynomial of degree 2.